# Generalized mean inequality for traces

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, determinant, trace, means

I came across [the following inequality for the determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Upper_and_lower_bounds):

$$
\frac{n}{\mathrm{tr}(A^{-1})}\leq \det (A)^{1/n}\leq \frac{1}{n}\mathrm{tr}(A)\leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\mathrm{tr}(A^{2})}
$$

which looks suspiciously like the HM-GM-AM-QM inequality:

$$
\frac{n}{a^{-1}+b^{-1}+\dots}\leq (a b\cdots)^{1/n}\leq \frac{a+b+\dots}{n}\leq \sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+\dots}{n}}.
$$

Of course, the later is generalized to the [generalized mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean):

$$\left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}
\le \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^q \right)^{\frac{1}{q}}
\quad\text{for}\quad p \le q.
$$

My question is whether the trace/determinant inequality generalizes in a similar way? such that:

$$
\left(\frac{1}{n}\mathrm{tr}(A^{p})\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \le
\left(\frac{1}{n}\mathrm{tr}(A^{q})\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}
\quad\text{for}\quad p \le q \text{?}
$$

This seems like something that would be true, but I wonder if it has a name, and if there is an intepretation of $\left(\frac{1}{n}\mathrm{tr}(A^{p})\right)^{1/p}$ as $p\to-\infty$ or $p\to\infty$, like there is for means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is. You can show it by noting that $\operatorname{tr}(A^{p})$ is just the sum of the eigenvalues of $A^p$, and that the eigenvalues of $A^p$ are just the eigenvalues of $A$ raised to the power $p$, $\forall p\in\Bbb{N}$. But of course the eigenvalues need to be real.

Comment: Ah, that's nice. So that proves it for positive semidefinite matrices? Maybe this is also the only place it holds, since otherwise we might not be able to take the root of the trace?

Comment: Exactly, and the similarity is not coincidental... It is actually am-gm-hm-qm inequality with the eigenvalues.