# Inequality for Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, hermitian-matrices

Does the following equality hold for $A,B$ ( both Hermitian matrices):
$$\vert \text{tr}(AB) \vert \leq \displaystyle\left(\text{tr}(\vert A\vert^k) \text{tr}(\vert B \vert ^k)\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}?$$

I remember seeing this for $k=2$, which can be treated roughly as Cauchy-Schwartz for Hermitian operators. But I don't recall the proof for it.
If it helps, you can assume k to be even.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Can you please suggest a reference?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator_on_Hilbert_space#Spectral_theorem

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I can see that right hand side is expressable as multiplication of individual $k$-norms (treating eigenvalues sequence as elements of $l^k$). The issue I am facing here is $A$ and $B$ may not be diagonalizable in the same basis. So, I don't exactly see how to write it as one norm.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Also, doesn't the norm decrease with $p$?

Comment: You are right. My fault. I had in mind H\"older inequality as in Answer 2. In general the inequality fails because you can take $A=B$ and then the norm decreases as you have noticed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\tr{\operatorname{Tr}}$You run into all kind of problems if you omit absolute values. For instance with $k=1$ and $$A=B=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ you have
$$
\tr(AB)=1>\tr(A)\,\tr(B)=0.
$$
In fact, the inequality fails even if $A,B$ are positive and commute. For instance with $A=B=I_2$, and any $k>2$,
$$
\tr(AB)=2>2^{2/k}= \tr(A^k)^{1/k}\tr(B^k)^{1/k}.
$$
The inequality that does hold is Holder's. That is, for $p,q≥1$ with $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$,
$$
|\tr(AB)|≤\tr(|A|^p)^{1/p}\tr(|B|^q)^{1/q}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the absolute signs. I think the intended inequality is different from Holder's.  I want the same exponent on both terms (which could potentially be restricted to even numbers (as mentioned in the question), which I believe takes care of absolute sign).

Comment: @Root: odd  powers would not take care of signs. In any case, my anwer includes a concrete counterexample for your inequality, with positive operators (that commute, to boot).

Comment: What is $|A|$? Is it a matrix norm of $A$?

Comment: No, it's the absolute value. It's $(A^*A)^{1/2}$ (or $A^TA)^{1/2}$ if $A$ is real).

Comment: @MartinArgerami Ah thanks very much, I somehow have not encountered this notation/terminology before.

Comment: No problem. It is very commonly used in operator theory and in matrix inequalities.

Answer (score 0):

One can show that for matrices of the same shape (not necessarily square), the following is an inner product. $$\langle A, B \rangle := \operatorname{tr}(A^\top B).$$
Then, Cauchy-Schwarz directly implies $$\operatorname{tr}(A^\top B) \le \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(A^\top A) \operatorname{tr}(B^\top B)}.$$
In the special case where $A$ and $B$ are square and symmetric, this becomes $\operatorname{tr}(AB) \le \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(A^2) \operatorname{tr}(B^2)}$. I don't know whether your claim holds for other $k$ though.

Comment: Perhaps this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2564697/generalized-mean-inequality-for-traces) can helps.